# Does the Salesforce REST API allow only one connection at a time like the SOAP API?

Tags: c#, salesforce

So according to the documentation for the SOAP api for Salesforce, if I log in and start a process that takes 1 minute before I log out, then someone else logs in with the same credentials and begins another process that takes 30 seconds before logout, when the second user logs out, it will kick out the first user as well.

Does the REST api have this issue? Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a session management issue more than any specific API you want to call using that session. that said, you have 2 easy options.

a) don't call logout, just let the sessions expire based on inactivity, that way if the session happens to be shared by 2 different integrations it won't cause a problem.

b) switch to OAuth to do your authentication, and give each integration its own OAuth client/remote access entry. (sessions are not shared between different oauth clients).

Answer (score 2):

The answer of your question is YES, REST Api has the same issue.

From official documentation:

> If multiple client applications are logged in using the same user,
>   **they all share the same session**. If one of the client applications
>   calls logout(), it invalidates the session for all the client
>   applications. **Using a different user** for each client application makes
>   it easier to avoid these limits.

The only way that salesforce recommends us to avoid this is creating new users.

You could make your own central service to manage the unique session, and give the active access token to clients, but this approach is away force.com platform solutions.

Comment: don't call logout, sessions != connections